# Equal, but Test fails

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I get this error:

```
AssertionError: [{'a': 20220, 'b': 1623}] != [{'a': 20220, 'b': 1623}]
```

Both sides seem to be equal, but the assertEqual() fails.

The error message looks strange, since both sides look identical.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

On one side was a dict and on the other side a result of django ORM:

```
self.assertEqual([{'a': a.id), 'b': int(b.id)}], Foo.objects.filter(b=b).values())
```

After adding list() around the result of the django ORM it works:

```
self.assertEqual([{'a': a.id), 'b': int(b.id)}], list(Foo.objects.filter(b=b).values()))
```

Comment: Dear down voting user: Please leave a comment why you think this solution is not good.

Comment: It looks like I accidentally clicked the wrong bit of the screen when reading this on my iPhone. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to want to let me cancel the vote. :(

Answer (score 0):

When comparing a queryset to a list, you should consider using [`assertSequenceEqual`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertSequenceEqual).

Alternatively, if the ordering of the result is of no significance, you should use the poorly named [`assertCountEqual`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertCountEqual) ([`assertItemsEqual`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertItemsEqual) in python 2).